# std::distance for iterators worse then RandomAccessIterator

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, stl, c++14

I recently reviewed not long ago implemented [algorithm](https://github.com/tomilov/quickhull/blob/master/include/quickhull.hpp) and found, that [it can be improved](https://github.com/tomilov/quickhull/commit/7a9735cbdcea040f5a9e3db5e190164683341e81) to be able to operate on not just only RandomAccessIterator input range, but even on ForwardIterator one (*multipass guarantee* is still the requirement).

I decide to simply downgrade the requirement by modifying all the places in the code, that currently uses simple difference between iterators, in a way to use `std::distance` instead. The `std::distance` [algorithm described here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance). Due to very nature of `std::distance` algorithm the modifications was not just a *search and replace* one, namely:

- For ordered containers internally used in the algorithm I replaced all occurences of `operator <` or `std::less< iterator >`/`std::less<>` with:

```
auto const less = [ibeg = std::cbegin(input)] (iterator const & l, iterator const & r)
                   {
                       return std::distance(ibeg, l) < std::distance(ibeg, r);
                   };
```

Say, `std::set< iterator > x;` modified to be `std::set< iterator, decltype(less) > x{less};`.

- For unordered containers internally used in the algorithm (`value_type` is `iterator`) I use `std::hash< std::intptr_t > h;` hash function for simple difference `h(lhs - rhs)` (actually *xor* combination of hash values, but it not matters here) for some fixed `iterator lhs` and a number of varying `iterator rhs`. It modified to be `h(std::distance(lhs, rhs))`.

The former point is correct, but the latter is evidently no. Due to `rhs` can be unrecheable from `lhs` just only by means of simple incrementation and there is no way to know what to do a priori: to increment `lhs` to reach `rhs` or to increment `rhs` to reach `lhs`.

But above hash still works. It is strange... because sometimes, when `lhs > rhs` (in some sense), there should be access violation (sometimes). Say, if:

```
std::list< int > input{1, 2, 3, 4};
auto a = std::begin(input), b = std::next(lhs, 2);
```

then increments, contained into `std::distance(b, a)`, should never stop and eventually reaches boundary of not yet allocated memory page. But AV never happens in my program. `std::distance` always return non-negative number.

Is it undefined behaviour or is it permittable to apply `std::distance` for any pair of ForwardIterator-s? The `-stdlib=` is `libc++`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [...] is it permittable to apply `std::distance` for any pair of `ForwardIterator`-s?

If you want to stick to the standard, then clearly **no, it's not permitted**:

> ```
> template <class InputIterator>
> typename iterator_traits<InputIterator>::difference_type distance(
>   InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
> ```
>
> [...]
>   Requires: If `InputIterator` meets the requirements of random access iterator, `last` shall be reachable from `first` or `first` shall be reachable from `last`; otherwise, *`last` shall be reachable from `first`*.
>
> [N4431 §24.4.4/5]

The reason is that for forward iterators the function is repeatedly applying `operator++` to get from `first` to `last`:

> Since only random access iterators provide + and -operators, the library provides two function templates `advance` and `distance`. These function templates use `+` and `-` for random access iterators (and are, therefore, constant time for them); for input, forward and bidirectional iterators they use `++` to provide linear time implementations.
>
> [N4431 §24.4.4/1]

Answer (score 2):

From the documentaton you linked "If `InputIt` is not `RandomAccessIterator`, the behavior is undefined if `last` is not reachable from `first` by (possibly repeatedly) incrementing `first`".

Undefined behaviour does not mean an access violation; it means anything at all, including returning some positive number.